# Unable to determine what esp is pointing to

Tags: x86

I'm going through the book Practical Malware Analysis (specifically, Lab07-03) and I've been stuck on a rather simple problem. I've divided the code section of `main()` into three parts to ease my analysis. (Note: I'm assuming the stack is growing downwards here.)

```
Part 1) mov eax, [esp+argc]
sub esp, 44h
cmp eax, 2

Part 2) push ebx
push ebp
push esi
push edi
jnz ExitProgram

Part 3) mov eax, [esp+54h+argv]
mov esi, offset hardcodedString
mov eax, [eax+4]
```

Part 1:

This looks simple enough, the stack pointer (`esp`) is added with the memory location of `argc` and the value at that address is saved in the `eax` register. Then *44h* is subtracted from `esp` to make room for some local variables of the main function. Finally, `eax` is compared to 2 and the appropriate flags are set in the flag register (the value of `eax` is not modified).

Part 2: Based on a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736437/why-does-gcc-push-rbx-at-the-beginning-of-main) question on StackOverFlow, it seems that the registers are pushed in Part 2 as they are callee save registers. This seems to be true as when main exits, it is popping these *exact* registers. Is my understanding of this correct?

Part 3: I'm adding the variables below if that helps in correcting me.

```
.text:00401440 var_44          = dword ptr -44h
.text:00401440 var_40          = dword ptr -40h
.text:00401440 var_3C          = dword ptr -3Ch
.text:00401440 var_38          = dword ptr -38h
.text:00401440 var_34          = dword ptr -34h
.text:00401440 var_30          = dword ptr -30h
.text:00401440 var_2C          = dword ptr -2Ch
.text:00401440 var_28          = dword ptr -28h
.text:00401440 var_24          = dword ptr -24h
.text:00401440 var_20          = dword ptr -20h
.text:00401440 var_1C          = dword ptr -1Ch
.text:00401440 var_18          = dword ptr -18h
.text:00401440 var_14          = dword ptr -14h
.text:00401440 var_10          = dword ptr -10h
.text:00401440 var_C           = dword ptr -0Ch
.text:00401440 hObject         = dword ptr -8
.text:00401440 var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:00401440 argc            = dword ptr  4
.text:00401440 argv            = dword ptr  8
.text:00401440 envp            = dword ptr  0Ch
```

I also don't understand the instruction `mov eax, [esp+54h+argv]`. It looks like the first argument that is passed to the program is being saved in `eax`, so wouldn't `mov eax, [esp+44h+argv]` make more sense? I recognize the function of the instruction `mov eax, [eax+4]` is to fetch the actual input passed to the program (i.e. `argv[1]`), which is what makes the previous instruction's indexing so confusing.

The `mov esi, offset hardcodedString` is just moving the address of the first character of the string into `esi`, so it looks good to me.

I'd appreciate some help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

esp had 0x44 subtracted, then an additional three registers pushed, so esp is now -0x50.  Then the access is 0x50+argv+4, which is argv[1].

Comment: But extended registers are 4 bytes in size, so after pushing the three registers, esp should be -56h right? Adding [54h+argv] would then bring esp to 06h, which is in the middle of argv?

Comment: 0x44+(3*4=0x0c)=0x50.

Comment: apologies for the late reply - looks like I accepted your solution only in my mind. . I do not know why I messed up such a simple calculation!